# Refresh stream content

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When pres play it connects to stream and its all ok!
When I click pause btn it stops sound, but the problem 
is when you click play btn after them it starts playing stream from the same place where you stop it, doing this all time nothing happens it always start stream from the same place when do it 1st time...

```
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound);

var fl_SC:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;
var fl_ToPlay:Boolean = true;
var s:Sound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://85.254.49.110:8002/radiov");
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true);


function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToPlay)
 {
    s.load(req, context);
    fl_SC = s.play();
    pause_btn.visible=true;
    play_btn.visible=false;
    spiner_mc.visible=true;

}
else
{
    fl_SC.stop();
    pause_btn.visible=false;
    play_btn.visible=true;
    spiner_mc.visible=true;
}
fl_ToPlay = !fl_ToPlay;
```

}

Comment: I tried your code and it played fine but after stopping (`fl_SC.stop();`) and then trying to replay with play btn I got a "Error: Error #2037: Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful."

Comment: PS: see this for the correct way to play "streaming" bytes from radio.. [ [AS3 Radio Play Link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/icecast-streams.html) ]. If you stick with sound object anyways then to refresh you need to do the `new URLRequest` part inside play function and there is also `sound.close` to consider also. See [ [Sound docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) ]

Answer (score 0):

everything was easy!

```
var fl_SC:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;
var fl_ToPlay:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToPlay)
{
    var s:Sound = new Sound();
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://85.254.49.110:8002/radiov");
    var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true); 
    s.load(req, context); 
    fl_SC = s.play();
    pause_btn.visible=true;
    play_btn.visible=false;

 }
 else
 {
     fl_SC.stop();
     pause_btn.visible=false;
     play_btn.visible=true;
    }
    fl_ToPlay = !fl_ToPlay;
}
```

The s:Sound, req, context and s.load cant be placed outside and thats all...